# In JavaScript onClick: why stroke appears then disappears?

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling, dom-events

I am using this code but the stroke appears and directly disappears when I click:

```
var tag = document.getElementById("tag");
function result()
{
  $(tag.value).css('border','1px solid red');
}
```

---

```
<button id="showBtn" onclick='result()'>Show</button>
```

but when I change the event type to "onmouseover" , the stroke stays and doesn't disappear.

Comment: What exactly is the tag (input, div, ...)?

Comment: And what is its value?

Comment: @IT pro - please show your **HTML code OR make JSFiddle** for more understanding

Comment: Wild guess (since not enough code/HTML has been disclosed): You may be calling `document.getElementById("tag");` too early before the document has loaded.

Comment: You may wish to remove the "stroke" in an `onmouseleave` handler

Answer (score 0):

As jfriend00 said, you are calling document.getElementById too early. Try:

```
function result() {
    $(tag).css("border", "solid 1px red");
}
var tag;
$(function() {
   tag = document.getElementById("tag"); 
});
```

**Edit after Thilo comment:**

```
var tag;
$(function() {
   tag = document.getElementById("tag"); 
});

function result() {
    $("#" + tag.value).css("border", "solid 1px red");
}
```

Assuming your HTML is something like:

```
<input id="tag" value="rect"></input>
<button id="showBtn" onclick='result();'>Show</button>
<div id="rect">This is a Div</div>
```

Comment: you are missing the `.value` part.